# Define isEven in terms of isOdd in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, boolean

I'm working on a Codecademy exercise:

> Remember the functions isOdd and isEven from Exercise 3.4?
>
> We'd like you to code them here again! But this time, the aim is to define one function in terms of the other using the ! symbol.
>
> Define isOdd, and then define isEven in terms of isOdd.

I tried a few different ways that I though would work,
like `console.log(!isOdd(1));`
and
`(n !% 2 ===)`,
none of them are right.

Here is the code that I have:

```
var isOdd = function (n)
{
 if (n % 2 ===0)
{
 return false;
} else {
 return true;
}
};
var isEven =function (n)
{
 if (n % 2 === 0)
{
 return true;
} else {
 return false;
}
};
console.log(isOdd(1));
console.log(isOdd(2));
console.log(isOdd(999));
```

Comment: Well you certainly did not define `isEven()` in terms of `isOdd()` using the `!` operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's straightforward:

```
var isEven = function (n)
{
    return !isOdd(n);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about that.  The answer is always so simple.  Well thanks very much.  I will be sure to write this one down on paper, over and over.

Answer (score 1):

```
var isOdd = function(n){
 if (n % 2 !== 0)  {
 return true;
 }  else  {
 return false;}
 };

var isEven = function(n){
 return !isOdd(n) ;
 };
 console.log(isOdd(11));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     var isOdd = function(){
    if(isEven){
        return isEven();
    } else {
        return false;
    }       
};
var isEven = function (){
    return true;
};

console.log(isOdd());
```

Answer (score -1):

These answers are wrong by definition.

A number is an integer and float.

All submitted answers are good for integers.

Here are proper tailored responses.

```
function isEven(n) { // covers all
    return (n).toString(2).endsWith(‘0’) // binary format
}

function isEven_integer(n) {
    return (n & 1) === 0;
}

function isEven_float(n) {
    // floats only, but works on integers.// faster for floats
    return ((n).toString()[(n).toString().length-1] % 2) === 0; // base 10
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 var isOdd = function(n)
{
    if(n%2 !== 0)
    { return ("odd");}
};    

var isEven = function (n)
{
 return !isOdd(n);
};

console.log(isEven(8));
```

Comment: I did it in codecademy it shows right but something is incorrect in output.. please check it..

Comment: This code does not define isEven in terms of isOdd, and as such is not an answer to the original question.

Comment: Because of a flaw in the validation code, most likely. Please refer to @Ned Batchelder's answer, above, for a correct implementation.

Comment: this hint was provided that's why i just done this
------------------------------------------

To define the isOdd function, you will need to use:

a) The modulo % symbol.
b) If / else statement in the body of the function

Comment: I was referring to the "define isEven in terms of isOdd" part of the assignment, not the implementation of isOdd itself (which is perfectly fine in your code, by the way).

Comment: @NamidaAneskans thanks for your quick reply.... but I'm also confused at this point.... Because right now I have stared playing with javascript